UseConsumeFilter with Batch Consumers causing a NullReferenceException during startup
Trying to use consume/publish filters for logging purposes and everything was going smooth until I came across a microservice that uses batch consumers, where it will throw a nullreferenceexception if a batch consumer is registered.
Here's how our MassTransit is configured:
services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{
    config.AddConsumers(typeof(MyNonBatchConsumer).Assembly);
    
    config.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UsePublishFilter(typeof(LoggingPublishFilter<>), provider);
        cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(LoggingConsumeFilter<>), provider);     

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint($"{typeof(Startup).Namespace?.Replace(".", "_")}_{environment.EnvironmentName}", receiveEndpointConfig =>
        {
            //tried registering the filter here as well, didn't work
            receiveEndpointConfig.ConfigureConsumer<MyNonBatchConsumer>(context);
            //Batch consumer
            receiveEndpointConfig.ConfigureConsumer<MyBatchConsumer>(context);
        });
    }));
});

services.AddScoped(typeof(LoggingPublishFilter<>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(LoggingConsumeFilter<>));

This is how our batch handler looks like:
public class MyBatchConsumerHandler : 
    IIntegrationEventBatchHandler<MyBatchConsumer>
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public MyBatchConsumerHandler(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Batch<MyBatchConsumer>> context)
    {
        //removed for brevity
    }
}

Exception seems to be thrown from the ConsumerMessageConfigured<TConsumer, TMessage>(IConsumerMessageConfigurator<TConsumer, TMessage> configurator) method of ScopedConsumerConsumePipeSpecificationObserver class, because configurator is null for batch handlers.
For the record, both the consume filter and the batch consumer work fine separately, just can't get them to work together.
My question is, how can I properly configure MassTransit to use both consume filters with batch consumers without running into a NullReferenceException? Is there a specific way to handle batch consumers when using filters that I might be missing?

If you're having an issue with MassTransit, you'll need to create a discussion on GitHub and share a complete repository demonstrating the problem. SO is not a support pathway.

My bad, updated a post to include an actual question. I don't have an issue with MassTransit per se(as in, I don't think it's a bug or impossible to do what I want to do), just wondering what configuration I could change to make the filter work for the normal and batch consumers.
